# My shape tween isn't reporting its size correctly

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

If I **shape tween** between two rectangles like so:

[image]

On frame 5 I have the following:

```
trace(width);
trace(height);
trace(getRect(this));
trace(getBounds(this));
```

I get back

```
49
49
(x=45, y=21, w=48, h=48)
(x=44.5, y=20.5, w=49, h=49)
```

All **wrong**! These would be right for frame 1 but the rectangle is much wider than this by frame 5. The shape tween seems to be confusing the results.

How can I get the actual rectangle of frame 5 without adding keyframes all across the timeline?

Comment: I don't think this will be possible using shape tweens.  Is it possible for you to make the shape a movieclip and use classic tweens instead?

Comment: My real example is a little more complicated than a rectangle scaling :) Otherwise I would. Out of interest, *why* is this impossible? I see there is a `MorphShape` instance which should be handling this stuff.

Comment: I don't have a reason why, it's just a guess based on a few years of experience with Flash's shortcomings, hence being a comment rather than an answer. I would love to see a solution though. Presumably you don't want to hard code the final dimensions from frame 9 into script on frame 1?

Comment: I can work with largest dimensions across animations, and then work in frame-by-frame and pixel-by-pixel on each size, to get extents of each frame. But it isn't the way I would like to do it obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a post about how to get the bounds of a display Object, even with tranparent areas here on my blog. It explains the code below.
http://plasticsturgeon.com/2010/09/as3-get-visible-bounds-of-transparent-display-object/

```
package util
{
   import flash.display.DisplayObject;
   import flash.display.BitmapData;
   import flash.geom.Rectangle;
   import flash.geom.Matrix;
   public function getVisibleBounds(source:DisplayObject):Rectangle
   {
       // Updated 11-18-2010;
       // Thanks to Mark in the comments for this addition;
       var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix()
       matrix.tx = -source.getBounds(null).x;
       matrix.ty = -source.getBounds(null).y;

       var data:BitmapData = new BitmapData(source.width, source.height, true, 0x00000000);
       data.draw(source, matrix);
       var bounds : Rectangle = data.getColorBoundsRect(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x000000, false);
       data.dispose();
       return bounds;
   }
}
```

If you feed in the display Object that contains you shape tween, you will get accurate with and height as well as corner bounds.

Comment: I like the spirit of this answer -- it's kind of what I wanted anyway -- but currently it's reporting `(x=3, y=21, w=46, h=28)` which is miles off.

Comment: you're missing a `bounds.offset(-matrix.tx, -matrix.ty)` to bring the rectangle back to source coordinates. Still too small though. I think the problem is that `getBounds` gives too small a rectangle, rather than too big.

Comment: ah! ok, so if I add a transparent layer behind the whole animation, it stretches the `getBounds` out enough that it can find the entire animation. Then your code reduces it down again to the correct size. Seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

Try multiplying by the scale to get the real width and height:

```
var realWidth:Number = scaleX * width;
var realHeight:Number = scaleY * height;
```

**Edit:**

How about calculating the dimensions yourself?

```
// Values roughly based on your screenshot, but you might need to adjust them
var startWidth = 10;
var endWidth = 100;
var startFrame = 5;
var endFrame = 10;
var currentWidth = startWidth + ((startFrame - currentFrame) / endFrame) * (endWidth - startWidth);
// Then the same for currentHeight
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, this is a simplified example :( My real situation is not a rectangle, has multiple tweens, and with easing applied.

Comment: @Chris Burt-Brown, In general, I wouldn't rely on getting proper values from things on the timeline. Depending on your animation, it might be possible to simply hardcode some values by yourself (startWidth and endWidth) and calculate the real width from that, based on the current frame (See edited post).

Comment: This is actually a pretty legitimate use of `getBounds` though; I'm "flattening" an animation into a series of BitmapDatas and just need to know what size BitmapData to create for each frame. So the kludge in this case is to create maximum-extent bitmaps and then trim them empty columns/rows at a time. Which is very ugh.

Comment: My guess is that the Tween is somehow wrapping your rectangle inside another Sprite, and is then scaling this new Sprite. So to get the real dimensions you might need to somehow access this wrapper sprite.

Comment: There's one instance of `MorphShape`. scaleX/Y are both 1 and `MorphShape` isn't a `DisplayObjectContainer` so if it has a notion of "children", I can't get to it. But this problem doesn't change in the presence of a more complicated shape tween like rectangle to squiggly polygon, which isn't a scale job.

Comment: If you put your shape into a MovieClip and measure that, is that accurate?